# How identify previous low or high from zigzag

Tags: mql4

this is icustom calling function and get low ang high value.

```js
double highzigzag = iCustom(NULL,0,"ZigZag",InpDepth,InpDeviation,InpBackstep,1,0);
      double lowzigzag = iCustom(NULL,0,"ZigZag",InpDepth,InpDeviation,InpBackstep,2,0);
```

And how can code previous low and high value to compare as

if previous low > current low  ,continue trend

if previous low < current low ,trend change

[zigzag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkBxW.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the last placeholder at the function "iCustom(......,X)" is the number of the Bar u want to check in your code: `double highzigzag = iCustom(NULL,0,"ZigZag",InpDepth,InpDeviation,InpBackstep,1,HERE); double lowzigzag = iCustom(NULL,0,"ZigZag",InpDepth,InpDeviation,InpBackstep,2,HERE);`

u are checking with 0 = Current OpenBar

u need to change it to 1=First Finished Bar or 2=Second Finished Bar as example

```
double highzigzag = iCustom(NULL,0,"ZigZag",InpDepth,InpDeviation,InpBackstep,1,1);
  double lowzigzag = iCustom(NULL,0,"ZigZag",InpDepth,InpDeviation,InpBackstep,2,1);
```

in this example i'm checking the first finished bar but instead of typing the bar number u should use the function within a for-loop and replace the bar number through "i"

if it helps dont forget to like

Answer (score 0):

Just to complet what has been said by @noSkill06s here is the loop

```
int    longRange  = 100;
double highzigzag = 0,
       lowzigzag = 0;

for(int i = 1;i<longRange;i++){

    highzigzag = 
iCustom(Symbol(),PERIOD_CURRENT,"ZigZag",InpDepth,InpDeviation,InpBackstep,1,i);
   if(highzigzag!=0) break;

}

for(int i = 1;i<longRange;i++){

lowzigzag = 
iCustom(Symbol(),PERIOD_CURRENT,"ZigZag",InpDepth,InpDeviation,InpBackstep,2,i);
if(lowzigzag!=0) break;

}


Comment("hight :"+highzigzag +"\nLow : "+lowzigzag );
```